# How can we define a 3-dimensional array of geometry?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I want to write a code for postgis in pgAdmin that is based on postgresql. It defines a 3-dimensional array of geometry.

I used this code for it:

```
DECLARE
    G geometry[9][9][9];
BEGIN
    for i IN 1..9 LOOP
    for j IN 1..9 LOOP
    for k IN 1..9 LOOP
        G[i][j][k] := [value that I want];
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
```

But it returned this error:

```
"array subscript out of range"
```

I used this instead:

```
DECLARE
    G geometry[9][9][9];
BEGIN
    for i IN array_lower(G, 1)..array_upper(G, 1) LOOP
    for j IN array_lower(G, 1)..array_upper(G, 1) LOOP
    for k IN array_lower(G, 1)..array_upper(G, 1) LOOP
        G[i][j][k] := [value that I want];
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
```

I have a different error this time:

```
"lower bound of FOR loop cannot be null"
```

I used this in BEGIN Part and solved all the errors:

```
G[1][1][1] := '01010000200400000000000000000000000000000000000000';
```

But I think this is not true and doesn't calculate all of the iterations for loops. I think this takes in account only the G[1][1][1]. What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, simply declaring the array dimensions does not initialize or pre-allocate anything. The array is dynamic in all its dimensions. That differs significantly from the multi-dimensional array implementations found in general programming language like `C`.

To mimic the logic of these languages, you may first initialize the 9x9x9 array with a statement like this:

```
G:=array_fill('point(0 0)'::geometry, array[9,9,9]);
```

Then the rest of the code will just work when refering to `G[i][j][k]` either as source or destination of assignments.

Comment: Yes. Assignments to big arrays are comparatively slow, though. [Craig provides details here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992339/why-is-postgresql-array-access-so-much-faster-in-c-than-in-pl-pgsql)