# Dynamic fieldnames in subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, dynamic-sql, unpivot

I have a table similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
  name character varying(15),
  q001001 numeric(9,0),
  q001002 numeric(9,0),
  q001003 numeric(9,0),
  q001004 numeric(9,0),
  q001005 numeric(9,0)
)
```

I need to query this table for the sums of various fields within, like this:

```
SELECT sum(q001001) as total001,
       sum(q001002) as total002,
       sum(q001005) as total005,
FROM stats;
```

This produces a result with ONE row of data, and THREE columns.
However, I need the results to be listed the other way around, for reporting purposes. I need THREE rows and ONE column (well, two actually, the first being the field that was sum'd) like this:

```
FieldName | SUM
----------+-------
q001001   |  12345
q001002   |  5432
q001005   |  986
```

I'd like to use some SQL like this, where the `field_name` (from a lookup table of the field names in the stats table) is used in a sub-query:

```
select l.field_name, (select sum(l.field_name) from stats)
from stats_field_names_lookup as l
where l.field_name in ('Q001001', 'Q001002', 'Q001005');
```

The thinking here is that `sum(l.field_name)` would be replaced by the actual field name in question, for each of those in the `WHERE` clause, and then evaluated to provide the correct sum'd result value. This, however, fails with the following error:

> function sum(character varying) does not exist

because the value there is a text/character. How can I cast that character value to an unquoted string to be evaluated properly?

This SQL works. But, of course, gives the same sum'd values for each `field_name`, since it is hard coded as `q001001` here.

```
select l.field_name, (select sum(q001001) from stats)
from stats_field_names_lookup as l
where l.field_name in ('Q001001', 'Q001002', 'Q001005');
```

So, I think the idea is sound in theory. Just need help figuring out how to get that character/string to be understood as a field_name. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Great question, especially from a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't know how to specify column names dynamically, but I suggest this way.

```
SELECT 'q001001' as FieldName, sum(q001001) as SUM FROM stats
UNION SELECT 'q001002' as FieldName, sum(q001002) as SUM FROM stats
UNION SELECT 'q001003' as FieldName, sum(q001003) as SUM FROM stats;
```

It's easy and would be a solution to your original problem.

Comment: Yeah, that'll work...   will just need to build a bit of logic to assemble the SQL statement properly.
Thanks very much!

Comment: @user3648665: It is inefficient to calculate each sum in a separate query. A single scan is substantially cheaper, the difference grows with the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

### Basic query

It's inefficient to calculate each sum separately. Do it in a single `SELECT` and "cross-tabulate" results.
To keep the answer "short" I reduced to two columns in the result. Expand as needed.

#### Quick & dirty

Unnest two arrays with equal number of elements in parallel. Details about this technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992339/why-is-postgresql-array-access-so-much-faster-in-c-than-in-pl-pgsql/16994266#16994266).

```
SELECT unnest('{q001001,q001002}'::text[])       AS fieldname
      ,unnest(ARRAY[sum(q001001), sum(q001002)]) AS result
FROM   stats;
```

"Dirty", because unnesting in parallel is a non-standard Postgres behavior that is frowned upon by some. Works like a charm, though. Follow the links for more.

#### Verbose & clean

Use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) and `UNION ALL` individual rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT sum(q001001) AS s1
         ,sum(q001002) AS s2
   FROM   stats
   )
SELECT 'q001001'::text AS fieldname, s1 AS result FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'q001002'::text, s2 FROM cte;
```

"Clean" because it's purely standard SQL.

#### Minimalistic

Shortest form, but it's also harder to understand:

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[
          ('q001001', sum(q001001))
         ,('q001002', sum(q001002))])
FROM   stats;
```

This operates with an array of **anonymous records**, which are hard to unnest (but possible).

#### Short

To get individual columns with original types, declare a type in your system:

```
CREATE TYPE fld_sum AS (fld text, fldsum numeric)
```

You can do the same for the session temporarily by creating a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE fld_sum (fld text, fldsum numeric);
```

Then:

```
SELECT (unnest(ARRAY[
           ('q001001'::text, sum(q001001)::numeric)
          ,('q001002'::text, sum(q001002)::numeric)]::fld_sum[])).*
FROM   stats;
```

Performance for all four variants is basically the same because the expensive part is the aggregation.
[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c395e/1) demonstrating all variants (based on [fiddle provided by @klin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23717374/939860)).

### Automate with PL/pgSQL function

#### Quick & Dirty

Build and execute code like outlined in the corresponding chapter above.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_list_of_sums1(_tbl regclass, _flds text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (fieldname text, result numeric) AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
SELECT '
   SELECT unnest ($1)
         ,unnest (ARRAY[sum(' || array_to_string(_flds, '), sum(')
                              || ')])::numeric
   FROM   ' || _tbl)
USING _flds;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Being "dirty", this is also ***not*** safe against SQL injection. Only use it with verified input.
  Below version is safe.

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_list_of_sums1('stats', '{q001001, q001002}');
```

#### Verbose & clean

Build and execute code like outlined in the corresponding chapter above.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_list_of_sums2(_tbl regclass, _flds text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (fieldname text, result numeric) AS
$func$
BEGIN

-- RAISE NOTICE '%', (      -- to get debug output uncomment this line ..
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (      -- .. and comment this one
SELECT 'WITH cte AS (
   SELECT ' || string_agg(
                  format('sum(%I)::numeric AS s%s', _flds[i], i)
                 ,E'\n         ,') || '
   FROM   ' || _tbl || '
   )
' || string_agg(
        format('SELECT %L, s%s FROM cte',  _flds[i], i)
      , E'\nUNION ALL\n')
FROM   generate_subscripts(_flds, 1) i
);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call like above.

#### Major points

- Implements the efficient code path to aggregate all sums in a *single* scan.
- Works for *any* table, not just `stats`.
- Works for *any* numeric columns (not just `numeric`).
- Safe against SQL injection which is a ***must*** for dynamic SQL.
  `format()` and `regclass` explained:
  [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- About unnesting an array with row numbers:
  [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Related answers demonstrating dynamic SQL in plpgsql built with `string_agg()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20string_agg%20format%20execute)

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c395e/1) demonstrating all variants.

### Aside: table definition

The data type `numeric(9,0)` is a rather inefficient choice for a table definition. Since you are not storing fractional digits and no more than 9 decimal digits, use a plain **`integer`** instead. It does the same with only **4 bytes** of storage (instead of 8-12 bytes for `numeric(9,0)`). If you need numeric precision in calculations you can always cast the column at negligible cost.
Also, [I don't use `varchar(n)` unless I have to. Just use `text`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)
So I'd suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
   name    text
  ,q001001 int
  ,q001002 int
  , ...
);
```

Comment: If you have a big / varying number of columns, you can build the statement dynamically by looking column names in the system catalog and use EXECUTE in a plpgsql function. [You'll find a number of code examples here, try a search.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A939860+[dynamic-sql]+[plpgsql]+EXECUTE]+pg_attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Using execute in plpgsql function. [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/40003/4/0).

```
create or replace function show_stats(field_names text[])
returns table ("FieldName" text, "SUM" numeric)
language plpgsql as $$
declare
    fname text;
begin
    foreach fname in array field_names loop
        return query execute format('
            select ''%s''::text, sum(%s) from stats',
            fname, fname);
    end loop;
end $$;

select * from show_stats(array['q001001', 'q001002', 'q001003', 'q001004']);
select * from show_stats(array['q001001', 'q001004']);
```